# Loading a multiframe/moving .gif image into python using pygame

Tags: python, loading, gif

Does anyone know a simple way to load a .gif image into python using pygame? I tried loading a .gif image using 'pygame.image.load(path)' which worked although only the first frame loaded.Ever since I had to use a loop to display multiple images at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot display multi-frame GIFs in Pygame, unless you use an extra library. Instead, explode your GIF. You will have to do everything manually, as Pygame does not control flow time, etc, which is necessary for animated GIFs.

Comment: Thanks bro, I've been searching for an answer everywhere, I guess I'll have to sick with my previous tactic.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. :-/